# How to write this complicated MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a *table* called `Users` and it has three *columns*  `Email , FB_Id , Google_ID`

The question is **how I can replicate following idea into just one MySQL query**.

1. Suppose someone login with FB_id then I should check in the DB if the email exist. If yes then update the related ID in this case FB_Id.

What I am trying to do is to keep all the id from different provider for a user. If a user has same user ID for google+ and Fb then we can have ID of both the provider for that email and my website will allow to login it in

The function that I have written is something Like this. Now I want to add the `UPDATE` action into this and then get the user details form the DB.

**Function**

```
function checkUpdate () {
    if ($this->email)
    {
       $query  =" SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email` ='".$this->email."'";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Email not exist ";
    }

    $rc = $this->parent->database->query($query);

    if (mysql_num_rows($rc)>0)
    {
        $this->flag_details = 'true';
    }

    while ($rfg=mysql_fetch_array($rc))
    {
        //print_r($rfg);

        $_POST['im_password'] = $rfg['Password'];
        $_POST['im_user'] = $rfg['Email'];
    }

}
```

**Update1**.

```
function checkUpdate () {
    if ($this->email)
    {
        $query  =" SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email` ='".$this->email."'";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Email not exist ";
    }

    $rc = $this->parent->database->query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($rc)>0)
    {
        $this->flag_details = 'true';

        //Here is my logic for it which I want to make in one sql query 
        if (isset($_POST['im_FbId']))
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET fb_id='".$_POST['im_FbId']."' WHERE id=2";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['im_GId']))
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET google_Id='".$_POST['im_GId']."' WHERE id=2";
        }

        $this->parent->database->query($sql);
    }

    while ($rfg=mysql_fetch_array($rc))
    {
        //print_r($rfg);

        $_POST['im_password'] = $rfg['Password'];
        $_POST['im_user'] = $rfg['Email'];
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `if else` statements are your way to go. I dont think what you want is possible in one statement.

Comment: Are you not using their API's?

Comment: @Dorvalla Oh yeah I had it using if else statement in my mind  . But I was thinking if I could chain it in one query :) . Thanks for the advice though

Comment: @MadsBjaerge yes I am using a plugin called hello.js  to connect to different service provider. Then I am sending credential to  DB using AJax() call.

Comment: maybe there is something possible with the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax` on MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Just an idea though.

Comment: @Vikram Oh wait, isn't that easy: `UPDATE FB_id = "id_from_facebook" WHERE email = "email_from_facebook"` ? Sounds like a plan

Comment: @pomeh yes but please check the function That I have added . I have to add the UPDATE action into this :) .

Comment: @Vikram I don't get your point. What is your question *exactly* ? Is it `how I can replicate following idea into just one MySQL query` or is it `Now I want to add the UPDATE action into this and then get the user details form the DB` ? Maybe try to add the pseudo-code you would like to have in your current code, because I'm not sure to understand your goal right now

Comment: @pomeh okay I will update my function with the current code that I have had . I am trying to doe all the stuff in one sql query .

Comment: @pomeh please have a look on my update

Comment: so you want run $sql to update both $_POST['im_FbId'] & $_POST['im_GId']  in one query but the have to be exists?

Comment: When I was starting out with SQL and tended to get stumped by anything more than a very basic query, I Googled for visual SQL query builders and found a few which did a god job.. You might try that, but don't become too reliant on a tool. Otoh, I have been surprised to see such a tool generate something more elegant than I can  :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly you want to update both or one of google id and facebook id

```
<?php

$sql = "UPDATE `users` ";
$sql .= isset($_POST['im_FbId']) ? " SET fb_id='{$_POST['im_FbId']}' " : "";
$comma = isset($_POST['im_FbId']) ? "," : "";
$sql .= isset($_POST['im_GId']) ? " {$comma}SET google_Id='{$_POST['im_GId']}' " : "";
$sql .= " WHERE id=2";

$this->parent->database->query($sql);
```

if only one exists for example $_POST['im_FbId'] the $sql value will be

```
    UPDATE `users` SET fb_id='facebook id' WHERE id=2
```

if both Id's exists the $sql value will be

```
    UPDATE `users` SET fb_id='facebook id' ,SET google_Id='google id' WHERE id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `users` SET FB_id='FACABOOK_FB_ID' WHERE EMAIL='FB_EMAI';